# How to switch the directory as the root directory in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I open my rails project using Atom, its root directory should be `hello_app`, but I open it from its outer folder `ruby_demo1`.

[image]

So, how can I set the `hello_app` folder as the outermost folder of my project in Atom?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Why can't you just open it from the folder you want at the root?